# What the minimum diameter/circumference a ringworld would have to have cycles of day and night and gravity Earth-like?

Tags: technology, earth-like, architecture

I wanted to know what the minimum diameter/circumference a ringworld would have to have cycles of day and night (24 hours complete) and gravity equal to Earth and what the speed of rotation.

Comment: Welcome Yorhan. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for your guidelines and a bit of dry reading. Enjoy the site.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ringworlds cannot have a day/night cycle resulting from rotation like planets can. Larry Niven's ringworld had the separate rotating bodies of "shadow squares" to mimic a day/night cycle.

Comment: Where does the day and night come from?

Comment: The day/night cycle would come from an inclination (about 140°) to the light source, thus illuminating a portion of the inner and outer part of the ring, blocking light to the inner part as the ring turns, the inside of the ring has periods of light and dark.

Answer (score 6):

**1.854 million kilometers**

That's not just a lower bound; that's the only radius your ring can be.

The math here is fairly simple. You want a wheel with one gee of centripetal acceleration at its rim, and a rotational period of 24 hours.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#Uniform_circular_motion):

Angular velocity $\omega = {2\pi \over T}$

Angular acceleration $a_c = \omega^2 r$

Substituting the first equation into the second, we get

$$a_c = \left(2\pi \over T\right)^2 r$$

Solve for $r$

$$r = {a_c T^2 \over 4 \pi^2}$$

Plugging in one gee and 24 hours for $a_c$ and T [yields a radius of 1.854×10^9 meters](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28one%20gee%20*%20%2824%20hours%29%5E2%29%20%2F%20%284pi%5E2%29).

That's about one million miles, six light-seconds, or 2.7 times the radius of the Sun.

That's not going to be a Ringworld encircling a star, unless it's a very small and dim star. Rather, this will be a megastructure orbiting a star in much the same way that Earth orbits the Sun.

This means that the ring will actually have a day-night cycle. The star will illuminate the interior of the ring, but only on the the side where the interior of the ring actually faces the star- that is, on the side farthest from the star. At "night", the star shines on the exterior of the ring, where nobody lives. (Although, come to think of it, that'd be a good place to put solar panels.)

The "nighttime" side of the ring will technically block some sunlight that would otherwise reach the "daytime" side. Exactly how much will depend on how wide the ring is.

Based on some quick WolframAlpha queries and some sketchy back-of-the-envelope algebra, I think that a ring that's ten thousand miles wide would just about eclipse the part "daytime" side that's directly behind the "nighttime" side. So if your ring is substantially narrower than that (say, one thousand miles wide), the interior will still get plenty of illumination. The sun will appear to be split in two, but it'll still be plenty bright.

And if you need the ring to be wider than that, you can always put it closer to the star.

Or, for that matter, tilt it a bit. There's no reason that the ring needs to be oriented in the same plane as its orbit. If the ring is tilted, sunlight will illuminate the entire "daytime" side of the ring, without the "nighttime" side occluding anything for most of the year. There will be a month-long (the exact duration depends on the ring's width and tilt) "eclipse" twice a year when the "nighttime" side of the ring does occlude part of the star; but for the rest of the year, the "daytime" side's view of the star will be unobstructed.

Interestingly, I'm fairly sure that these eclipses would occur in the middle of the ring's equivalent of "summer"; and that the seasons when the star is shining closest to face-on would be "winter". Imagine if the ring were tilted at 90 degrees: when the star is shining exactly face-on, the interior of the ring would hardly get any sunlight at all. The sun would be just barely above the horizon, and most if not all of the interior of the ring would be in the shade of the walls that keep the atmosphere from escaping.

Comment: It took me a couple of readings, but you're actually describing a Banksian Orbital. (https://en.everybodywiki.com/Orbital_(The_Culture)) which is quite different from a ringworld.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a minimum diameter for the specifications you describe. The starward side would always face the star, so there would be no day/night cycles. Niven put giant plates to block the sun for the night periods.

Similarly, there is no minimum diameter to have earth gravity. Closer to the sun, it would have to spin faster. The real problem would be that, if you get inside the goldilocks zone, it would burn all water off of the inside of the ring, even with night plates.

Thus, Niven went with 93 million miles (one AU) for the distance from the sun. [The results of the spin calculations can be found on C2.com](https://wiki.c2.com/?RingWorld)